# Camel cache usage

Tags: caching, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have implemented some routes in JBOSS Fuse which are exposed as REST Web service. I want to implement cache for web services. Lets say if request for same username for specific resource in specific time span return the cached response. Doing some research i got to know about camel cache component. I tried to read about it to check if camel component will help me in getting my objective done or not but got nothing on which i can decide.

If any one can suggest me any approach how to cache response on basis of request or if camel cache component can be used. If yes then suggest any startup tutorial for this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Camel EhCache](http://camel.apache.org/ehcache.html). There's a "getting started" on the docs. But you may take a look at the unit tests from this component [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-ehcache/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/ehcache).

That way you'll have a more detailed approach of how to use it. For example, the cache manager should leverage directly from the EhCache API:

```
CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()
                .withCache(
                    "myCache",
                    CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                    String.class,
                    String.class,
                    ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                        .heap(100, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                        .offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB))
).build(true)
```

Cheers!